# Unable to add specific custom domain to Azure Website (I have others working)

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I've read all about configuring custom domains for Azure Websites and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have many other custom domains setup within this same GoDaddy account pointing at this same Azure Website and working perfectly. I've done side-by-side comparisons of their A Records and CName Records and they look the same to me. What am I missing?

I've tried waiting for 6 hours or so for things to expire and take effect, but no difference. My other domains activated within 10min or so, so I don't think that's the problem.

Azure error next to the correct CNames in GoDaddy: https://db.tt/jx6aKzUQ

Here's a side-by-side of one which works (PortsHap.com) and the one which doesn't (LESHap.com). What am I missing?!

GoDaddy side-by-side: https://db.tt/1ZOclKU9

I did a DNS look-up of the CNames and they're being found properly: https://db.tt/wEarl1WW

I'm at a loss...

UPDATE:

I can't afford to be blocked by this any longer, so I just set up a different domain "LESHaps.com" and used it instead. I set it up with the same process, same settings, but now it works. It's utterly bizarre. This really seems like a bug in Azure Websites. If anyone has any thoughts on this, then I would love to hear them. I'll switch back to the on-brand domain if I find a way.

Comment: This is really critical for me. Anyone have any ideas at all? I've double checked everything I can think to.

Comment: Have you seen this article: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-godaddy-custom-domain-name/?  It might provide some step you missed

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yeah, I've gone over it several times. It's very mysterious why this isn't working. See my screenshots for details of how this config is identical to another which works properly, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you previously had that domain associated with a different Azure website? I've found that you can't associate a domain with more than one Azure website, and you have to remove it from the first website before associating this with a second.

This could be a real problem if you purchased a domain which had previously belonged to someone else, because you'd have no way of getting them to unassociate the domain, thus you couldn't use it in azure even if you own it!